# Functions problem, bijective, composite

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

$$f(x,y) = xy$$

$$f: \mathbb R \times\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$$

$$h(x) = (x, x^2)$$

$$h: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$$

Is $f(h)$ bijective, injective or surjective?  i don't quite understand what does $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ mean here, it's a textbook exercise, Thanks.
I think it's surjective but im not sure about injective.

Comment: Perhaps then you should read the earlier part of the textbook where it states what $A\times B$ means for sets $A$ and $B$, or at least for $A=B=\mathbb{R}$. Also, you're asking about $f\circ h$, the function whose value at $x$ is $f(h(x))$ — right? $h$ is a function not an ordered pair of real numbers, and it's not a possible argument for $f$ [so, don't write $f(h)$].

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is not injective as it maps the two ordered pairs (1,1) and (2,1/2) to the same point.Since it's not injective it's not bijective. $f$ is  surjective because for any $x\in R$ we have $f(x,1)=x$. And $h$ is injective because $h(x)=h(y)\to (x,x^2)=(y,y^2)\to (x=y\land x^2=y^2)\to x=y. $  It's not surjective because $h(x)\ne (1,0)$ for any $x$. It's not bijective because it's not surjective.A bijection is a surjective injection, or equivalently , an injective surjection.

Comment: what about h(f(x))??

Comment: The domain of f is RxR

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ means the set of ordered pair of real numbers. You're correct it's surjective as $f(h(x)) = f(x, x^2) = x x^2 = x^3$ so it's in fact bijective.

Answer (score 0):

R X R specifically refers to the cartesian product. It would be read aloud as "R cross R".